# How to cache images using service worker?

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, browser-cache, service-worker

I am new to the Angular world, I was following a tutorial and created a PWA app from the same. The app works fine when online, but when it goes offline it is unable to load images and looks bad.
I want to cache an image from the server and so that when the app goes offline, the recently loaded image shows up in the app.
I am sorry for my bad english, and thanks for taking interest in my problem.
My app link: [PWA app link](https://supremecoding.github.io/PWCat/)

Answer (score 2):

Your can enable ServiceWorker in Angular to cache images. By default, if you put your images under the `assets` folder, they would be cached.

> Notice that all of the files the browser needs to render this
>   application are cached. The ngsw-config.json boilerplate configuration
>   is set up to cache the specific resources used by the CLI:
>
> - index.html
> - favicon.ico
> - Build artifacts (JS and CSS bundles)
> - **Anything under assets.**

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#whats-being-cached